# Converting Array of URLs into Array of UIImage

Tags: swift

I have an array of URLs linking to image files, how do I store them into an array of UIImages?

```
var imagesArray = [UIImage]()

let links = ["http://example.com/image1.jpg","http://example.com/image2.jpg"] as [String]
```

There must be an easy solution.
If it was one image I could do something like the following:

```
let url = URL(string: link2image!)!
let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
self.image.append(image)
```

Comment: Have you considered using a forEach / map func? Either like `let images = urls.map({ (url) in let image = try? Data(contentsOf: url);... })` or `var images: [UIImage] = []; url.forEach({(url) in let img = Data(contentsOf: url); ... self.images.append(img); })` Know what I mean?

Comment: Storing a bunch of images in an array is a bad idea to start with.

Comment: Yeah that might actually do the job. I will give it a try to see what happens thanks.

Comment: `There must be an easy solution.` You need to learn the basics of asynchronous programming.

Comment: @JAL would you recommend PromiseKit too? I'm just using apple's native guard and async etc..

Comment: @adimona Not particularly, although I have used PromiseKit and Bolts in the past, there are ways to do this with closures without the use of an outside dependency.

Comment: Most of the capabilities of PromiseKit and the similar frameworks can be mimicked, but using `GCD` chaining async requests and especially propagating errors is way harder and more error prone than if you did the same using a 3rd party framework.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution would be to just iterate through the array and download the images synchronously using `Data(contentsOf:)`, however, this would be quite insufficient due to synchronous execution.

```
let images = links.flatMap{ link->UIImage? in
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else {return nil}
    guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {return nil}
    return UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

A better solution would be to download the images asynchronously in parallel, I have written a `UIImage` extension for this using [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit):

```
extension UIImage {
    class func downloadedAsync(fromUrl url: URL)->Promise<UIImage> {
        return Promise{ fulfill, reject in
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    reject(error!); return
                }
                guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    reject(NSError(domain: "Wrong HTTP response code when downloading image asynchronously",code: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 1000));return
                }
                guard let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"), let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
                    reject(NSError(domain: "No image in response", code: 700)); return
                }
                fulfill(image)
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

You call it for an array of links like this:

```
var imageDownloadTasks = links.flatMap{ link in
    guard let url = URL(string: link) else {return nil}
    return UIImage.downloadedAsync(fromUrl: url)
}
```

Then execute the promises:

```
when(fulfilled: imageDownloadTasks).then{ images in
    //use the images, images is of type [UIImage]
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, I'm not sure about the PromiseKit as I want to avoid using too many frameworks but I will give that first solution a try. Cheers

Comment: I would seriously recommend using the second solution, since the first one is really not ideal due to the synchronous execution. If you will be working with async requests a lot, `PromiseKit` is a real beast, it will make your life way easier. If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: PromiseKit is overkill for a task like this IMO.  This can be done with tools included in the native Cocoa SDK, such as NSURLSession.

Comment: Yeah using promises is pretty ideal, especially for this use case; I'd recommend giving it a try. Or you can try out a native approach, but doing the operation asynchronously maybe by using NSURL Session as @JAL suggested

Comment: @JAL if it is just this task, then yes, it can be solved using native resources, but it will require more code and will be more error prone. Especially for someone unfamiliar with asynchronous programming, solving such problem can be a pain using the built in frameworks.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Someone who doesn't know the basics of async programming should learn the basics first.  Using a framework is just a short cut, the OP will learn nothing if they rely on pre-built frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Functional programming use: map closure ...

```
links.map({
    if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: $0)!) {
        UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
})
```

But you must know if your links is wrong, it will crash. So, I suggest you make some guard to prevent these crashes. like this...

```
guard let url = URL(string: $0) else { return nil }
```

Comment: A better way would be to flatMap the strings to URLs and then flatmap then again to data/images.

Comment: Ok, Get it, I will try

Answer (score 0):

```
 for img in links {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: img)!) {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            imageArray.append(image!)
        }
    }
```